# Why is there a Trace/Breakpoint error using Delete[] in c++?

Tags: c++, class, typename

I am currently working on making a "vector" class.

```
template <typename T>
class Vectors{
private:
        int size_;
public:
        int size_;
        T *elements;
        Vector(){
            size_=0;
            T *elements=new T[size_];
        }
        Vector(int size){
            size_=size;
            T *elements=new T[size_];
        }
        void push_back(T amaze){
            //make new temporary pointer;
            T *Temp=new T[size_+1];
            size_=size_+1;
            for(int i=0;i<size_-1;i++)
                {
                    *(Temp+i)=*(elements+i);
                }
            delete[] elements; //Error occurs here
            elements=NULL;
            elements=Temp;
            *(elements+size_-1)=amaze;
        }
}
```

After running the debugger, I found out that there is a trace/breakpoints trap when the program reaches delete[] elements.

Why is this error occurring?

Comment: Where is elements being declared? And where is it being initialized? Where do you do elements = new ...

Comment: Sorry I didn't include it,  The post has been updated and I added T* elements in public.

Comment: A good practice would be to label your member variables with a prepended m_ so in this case m_elements. That way you won't have issues like this, and makes the functions easier to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable warnings, and you will see that you are not initializing the `elements` member but a variable:

```
T *elements=new T[size_];
```

So when you delete them, you are basically trying to delete a broken pointer that has never been allocated and points nowhere. This makes the program crash, effectively.

By the way, you should post the actual code you are running, because currently your class name is `Vectors`, plural; but the constructors are called `Vector`. A proper constructor would use initializer lists and would be `explicit`:

```
explicit Vector(std::size_t size)
: size_(size), elements_(new T[size_])
{
}
```

The default constructor should not try to allocate an array of size 0. Just keep `elements` as `nullptr`.

Answer (score 2):

Your constructors are not assigning anything to the class `elements` member. They are assigning to local variables of the same name, shadowing the class member.  So the class member is still uninitialized when `push_back()` tries to `delete[]` it.

Change

```
T *elements=new T[size_];
```

To

```
elements=new T[size_];
```

Also note that your class does not follow the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), as it lacks a destructor, copy constructor, and copy assignment operator. And it is declaring the `size_` member twice, which should fail to compile.

Try this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Vector{
private:
    int size_;
    int count_;
    T *elements;
public:
    Vector(){
        size_ = 0;
        count_ = 0;
        elements = new T[size_];
    }

    Vector(int size){
        size_ = size;
        count_ = 0;
        elements = new T[size_];
    }

    Vector(const Vector &v){
        size_ = v.size_;
        count = v.count_;
        elements = new T[size_];
        for(int i = 0; i < count_; ++i) {
            elements[i] = v.elements[i];
        }
    }

    ~Vector() {
        delete[] elements;
    }

    void push_back(T amaze){
        if (count_ == size_) {
            T *Temp = new T[size_ * 2];
            for(int i = 0; i < count_; ++i) {
                Temp[i] = elements[i];
            }
            delete[] elements;
            elements = Temp;
            size_ *= 2;
        }
        elements[count_]= amaze;
        ++count_;
    }

    void swap(Vector &other) {
        std::swap(elements, other.elements);
        std::swap(size_, other.size_);
        std::swap(count_, other.count_);
    }

    Vector& operator=(const Vector &v) {
        if (&v != this) {
            Vector(v).swap(*this);          
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```